# Do docusign API support dynamic PDF attachment and signature receiving field addition?

Tags: docusignapi

We want to send dynamically generated custom PDF documents to users for e-signature via email from DocuSign API, and get their signature back on the PDFs.

The length of the dynamic PDF will vary from a user to user. Can we place the signature field at the bottom of PDF no matter how long it is? It can be from 2 to 10 pages long.

1. Is this possible with DocuSign to send dynamically generated custom PDF for e-signature i.e when user open the document he/she should see the pdf that we will pass dynamically via API?
2. Also, what will be the PDF size limitations? I believe it is 25 MB?
3. Can we have flexibility in positioning the signature field based on the length of pdf? I believe there is a way to place field based on text, but how is this done with API?

We would be using both PHP SDK or C# SDK. Can you help us with any sample/example code for these SDKs?

Answer (score 1):

> The length of the dynamic PDF will vary from a user to user. Can we place the signature field at the bottom of PDF no matter how long it is?

Yes, use "Auto-place" positioning--also known as "Anchor Text" positioning for the Signer tabs/fields and other DocuSign fields that you add to the page. See the [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/tabs#tab-placement-method-2-auto-place-anchor-tagging).

> Is it possible with DocuSign to send dynamically generated custom PDF for e-signature i.e when user open the document he/she should see the pdf that we will pass dynamically via API?

Essentially, yes. Your app should dynamically generate the PDF for a signer, *then* use the DocuSign [Envelopes::create](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create) call to send the signing request, including the PDF you just created.

> Also, what will be the PDF size limitations? I believe it is 25 MB?

Generally speaking, that is the limit. If you start getting close to it, there are additional details to be considered. Ask another question if your PDFs are going to be that large.

> Can we have flexibility in positioning the signature field based on the length of pdf? I believe there is a way to place field based on text, but how is this done with API?

You add unique "anchor" text to the documents such as `/sig1/`, then, where ever that text appears, a DocuSign field will be added. See the Auto-position docs mentioned above. Because you don't want the signer to see the "/sig1/" text, the trick is to have its text color be white. That way, on a white background, it won't be visible.

> We would be using both PHP SDK or C# SDK. Can you help us with any sample/example code for these SDKs?

Some example code is available now on the [DevCenter](https://developers.docusign.com/). We will be adding more in the future, but not for a couple of months.